# My Ubuntu Precise 64 Bit PC's Boot Time is Two Minutes. Isn't that too much? Any Idea?

Tags: 12.04, boot, 64-bit, virtualbox, indicator

My Ubuntu PC boots up in 2 minutes. First minute goes for greeter session and the second minute goes for user login session. Is this normal?

My PC's main spesifications are as below:

1. Ubuntu release: 12.04 (precise) 64-bit
2. Kernel Linux 3.2.0-41-generic
3. RAM 3.0 GiB
4. Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P8700 @ 2.53GHz × 2
5. Available disk space: 185.7 GiB
6. Besides Unity I have GNOME 3.4.2 shell - KDE shell - XFCE-XUBUNTU shell installed in.
7. Also I have Oracle VM Virtualbox that Windows Vista 32 Bit installed in.
8. Loaded start up apllications are: Jupiter, Dropbox, Bluetooth, My-Weather-Indicator, System Load Indicator, Mozilla Thunderbird, battery status indicator, wireless, sound settings and the clock.

Any idea that will let me to make it faster?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you upgrade or fresh install? I found a fresh install over upgrade to be far swifter. Mind you 2 mins for C2D is excessive. Let us hope the community can help get to the bottom of it...

Comment: No I did not upgrade. It is a fresh install from CD. But I installed all programs stated in this [link] (http://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-desktop-ubuntu-12.04-lts-precise-pangolin)

Comment: This is too slow, if the above link doesn't help you, you can try to make a boot chart and post it in the Ubuntu Forums.

Answer (score 1):

It sure is too long... if it is an option, try updating to 13.04. I personally see massive improvements in startup and shutdown times. (For me startup is ~ 7-10 secs and shutdown is flat 2-3 secs.)

I am working on a normal disk ASUS K55VJ laptop with Intel graphics card working with NVIDIA 635M in optimus mode, 3rd gen i5 processor and 8 GB RAM

Comment: Stating your own boot times is not helpful unless you specify what hardware you use. -10 seconds on an SSD is different from -10 seconds on a normal drive.

Comment: Just inquisitive, are SSD drives faster? and also I was amazed with my timings, and thought it would help fire up the energy of someone else who sees it too. :)

Comment: Actually I prefer to use LTS distros. So uprading to Ubuntu 13.04 is not an option for me. Thank you. And wow... your PC might have stronger processors and RAM.